# Restarting of a SQL Server and OS restarting

Tags: windows, sql-server

After some manipulations with a SQL Server application a restarting of the SQL Server is required.

If we restart operation system, does this always mean that we restart SQL Server as well (it seems evident that it does, but just in case I ask to be sure)? Or there could be a situation when we should do it explicitely, for example by choosing context menu item "Restart" in SQL Server Configuration Manager?

I.e. could it be necessary for something to restart SQL Server while OS is working?

Comment: wow! badly worded question.  What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  When the OS restarts everything restarts.  Can't run anything if the OS is not running.  There can also definitely be times when you would restart SQL without requiring a server reboot.  A reconfig that only affects SQL Server and does not do anything with the underlying OS, for example, could require SQL to restart but wouldn't necessarily require a reboot.  Setting persistent trace flags is one example.